# emailext attachmentsPattern: '**/target/overview-features.html' gives exception

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

emailext attachmentsPattern: '**/target/overview-features.html' is giving Error in Jenkinsfile in Maven Project

```
post { 
  success { 
    emailext 
      attachmentsPattern: "**/overview-features.html", 
      body: '''${SCRIPT, template="groovy-html.template"}''', 
      mimeType: 'text/html',
      to: "test@gmail.com", 
      subject: "Success Pipeline: ${currentBuild.fullDisplayName}" 
  } 
}
```

Comment: please show the exception message and you pipeline code

Comment: post {
        success {
          emailext attachmentsPattern: "**/overview-features.html", 
          body: '''${SCRIPT, template="groovy-html.template"}''',
          mimeType: 'text/html',to: "abhishekgaur054@gmail.com", 
          subject: "Success Pipeline: ${currentBuild.fullDisplayName}"
               }
            }

Comment: Please show the error message too. Have you tried change to use single quote `'**/overview-features.html'`?

Comment: Single comment work out for me